# Interface: Nested Object types

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I'm trying to type an object with nested objects, but keep getting an error.

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"0x63564c40"' does not exist in type 'Network'.`

```js
export interface Network {
  network: {
    chainId: string;
    rpcUrls: string[];
    chainName: string;
    nativeCurrency: {
      name: string;
      symbol: string;
      decimals: number;
    };
    blockExplorerUrls: string[];
    iconUrls: string[];
  };
}

export const networkParams: Network = {
  "0x63564c40": {
    chainId: "0x63564c40",
    rpcUrls: ["https://api.harmony.one"],
    chainName: "Harmony Mainnet",
    nativeCurrency: { name: "ONE", decimals: 18, symbol: "ONE" },
    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://explorer.harmony.one"],
    iconUrls: ["https://harmonynews.one/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/slfdjs.png"],
  },
  "0xa4ec": {
    chainId: "0xa4ec",
    rpcUrls: ["https://forno.celo.org"],
    chainName: "Celo Mainnet",
    nativeCurrency: { name: "CELO", decimals: 18, symbol: "CELO" },
    blockExplorerUrl: ["https://explorer.celo.org"],
    iconUrls: ["https://celo.org/images/marketplace-icons/icon-celo-CELO-color-f.svg"],
  },
};
```

Why does it say so with the first, but not the second object?

Comment: It points out one error at a time. Try removing the first object and it will tell you that `'"0xa4ec"' does not exist in type 'Network'`

Comment: `networkParams` is supposed to implement `Network`, and `Network` does not have a key named `0x63564c40`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named the key network if you want it to be dynamic you can do that like this:

```
export interface Network {
  [key: string]: {
    chainId: string;
    rpcUrls: string[];
    chainName: string;
    nativeCurrency: {
      name: string;
      symbol: string;
      decimals: number;
    };
    blockExplorerUrls: string[];
    iconUrls: string[];
  };
}

export const networkParams: Network = {
  "0x63564c40": {
    chainId: "0x63564c40",
    rpcUrls: ["https://api.harmony.one"],
    chainName: "Harmony Mainnet",
    nativeCurrency: { name: "ONE", decimals: 18, symbol: "ONE" },
    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://explorer.harmony.one"],
    iconUrls: ["https://harmonynews.one/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/slfdjs.png"],
  },
  "0xa4ec": {
    chainId: "0xa4ec",
    rpcUrls: ["https://forno.celo.org"],
    chainName: "Celo Mainnet",
    nativeCurrency: { name: "CELO", decimals: 18, symbol: "CELO" },
    blockExplorerUrls: ["https://explorer.celo.org"],
    iconUrls: ["https://celo.org/images/marketplace-icons/icon-celo-CELO-color-f.svg"],
  },
};
```